# "dynamical" condition in Excel?

Tags: excel

I want to have a "dynamical" condition in Excel as follows:
in `Sheet2.Cell(C2)`

```
    If(AND(Sheet1!D2-Sheet1!C2<0;the sum of all cells, in the same row, however before
 the current cell which is in this example: Sheet2.Cell(C2)!=0);0;Abs(Sheet1!D2-Sheet1!C2))
```

I tried with `SUM` and `SUMIF` but the problem is within the first cell and after that if I drop the formula the area is still fixed.
Sincethe problem is complicated I give here one example constructed by me which hopefully helps to clarify the problem. In the following pic we see a time series 
[image]

the series in row 3 is permanently falling. The series in row 2 is from B2 to C2 falling but from C2 to D2 raising and the rest falling. Now In **sheet 2** I want to recognize if a time series from sheet1 shows EVEN just one time raising behaviour and if yes from that cell I will put the difference but not Zero. Like in the following pic[[image]]

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, for the dynamic part you can do like `$A$2:C$2` and drag across the column. It's a mix of absolute referencing to anchor the start and relative to have a dynamic endpoint.

Comment: One of the few times I can recall asking: Can you explain in words, and not using the code/formula?

Comment: yes you all are right it is a little bit complicated I hope that I was able to explain a little bit better

Answer (score 1):

That is not the most elegant solution but;
I calculated the first column (which is in my example B) as follows:

```
=IF((Sheet1!C2-Sheet1!B2)<0,0,ABS(Sheet1!C2-Sheet1!B2))
```

And in `C2` I wrote

```
=IF(AND((Sheet1!D2-Sheet1!C2)<0,SUM($B2:B2)=0),0,ABS(Sheet1!D2-Sheet1!C2))
```

then I  applied this formula to all fields! It works.

Disadvantage: the first column should be calculated before we would be able to apply it to the rest.

Comment: I think this is a good approach +1. I would still have been using an array formula which is not necessary and would have been slower.

Comment: I think in your second formula you meant to put SUM($B2:B2), otherwise you get a circular reference. You can actually put IF(AND((Sheet1!C2-Sheet1!B2)<0,SUM(A2:$A2)=0),0,ABS(Sheet1!C2-Sheet1!B2))  in sheet2!B2 because SUM does not error if you apply it to a cell containing a string, it just gives zero - try it. I will delete my answer.

Comment: You are right I correct it. Your Answer is elegant I used it but for another prepose. Probably, it needs a manipulation.